# How to share a table with external account using Lake Formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I need to share a table created in Glue with an external account.
Actually, it seems pretty easy, but for some reason the shared table doesn't show up in the tables list of the target account.

Here is what I have done in the source account:

1. Created the database and table in Glue.
2. Created "data lake location" pointing to the bucket where data is stored.
3. Revoked the IAMallowedPrincipals (otherwise it didn't allow me to grant access)
4. Granted permition to external account (12 digits) with select and describe.

In the target account:

1. Went to Resource Access Manager and accepted the shared resource.

Now, the table should be visible in the target account, but it is not there. Altough I can see the shared resource in the RAM.

Any ideas what is missing here?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to LakeFormation in the target account, click on "tables", select the share table (you can spot it by the "owner account id") and click on "Actions" and "create resource link".
Now you need to give this table a local name and choose in which database it should resides.
Click on "Create" and that's it - you can query it from Athena.